# How to show that This Linear map satisfies $T(f)=f'(0)$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

Show that any linear map $T: C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying

- (a) $T(1)=0$,
- (b) $T(x)=1$,
- (c) $T(fg) = f(0)T(g)+g(0)T(f)$
  is unique, and thus show that any such $T$ satisfies $T(f)=f'(0)$.

Now, I have proved that $T $ must be unique but I am not able to prove that $T(f)$ must be equal to $f'(0)$. I tried by putting $g=1 $ in  $T(fg) = f(0)T(g)+g(0)T(f)$ and and then differentiating , differentiating $T(fg) = f(0)T(g)+g(0)T(f)$ and then putting $g=1$ but they don't help with what I want to prove.

So, what approach should I use.

Comment: Well, if you have shown it's unique, surely showing that the map $T : C^\infty(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ defined by $T(f) = f'(0)$ satisfies these properties should do the trick? The only thing you really need to use here is the chain rule.

Comment: For the benefit of guys like me could you show how you proved uniqueness?

Comment: @No-One One nice way to approach this problem is to use Taylor's theorem to write $f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + x^2 h(x)$. Of course, this gives you the formula $T(f) = f'(0)$ as a means of showing uniqueness.

Comment: @Rushy Thanks !